# Как прокликать все элементы списка?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Нужно прокликать все ссылки в меню. На странице это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую вот так, но после первой итерации валится:

```
List<WebElement> elementList =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#box-apps-menu a"));

    for ( int i=0; i<elementList.size(); i++){
        elementList.get(i).click();
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так? Текст ошибки:

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Ну собственно, судя по всему, после первого клика происходит переход по ссылке. А на новой странице уже нет элемента по которому вы хотите кликнуть на второй итерации цикла.

Comment: https://automated-testing.info/t/obshhij-algoritm-resheniya-element-is-not-attached-to-page-document/13003/5 . Здесь про эту ошибку подробнее написано.

Comment: При клике на ссылку открывается подменю, остальные элементы присутствуют. Вот так это выглядит (http://take.ms/fca33)

Comment: Похоже, что не просто подменю открывается, а при этом еще перезагружается вся страница. Это так?

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, так и есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После того, как страница перезагружается, `elementList` больше не указывает на меню на новой странице. После перезагрузки нужно снова строить `elementList`, а в качестве итератора для нажимания по ссылкам использовать переменную. Примерно так:

```
List<WebElement> elementList  =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#box-apps-menu a"));
int numberOfListElements = elementList.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfListElements ; i++){
        elementList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#box-apps-menu a"))
        elementList.get(i).click();
        }
```

*Пару дней назад столкнулся с такой же проблемой и решил её этим способом. Но на другом языке, так что возможно этот код придется подправить.*